# How do I connect a .tk domain with google sites?

Tags: google-sites

Basically, I am trying to set up a google sites website with a cname from the .tk service.

I need to know what I have to modify in the "Use Dot TK Free DNS Service"

So far, this is the info I have: 
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2518318
http://www.blogritz.com/2011/03/change-blogspotcom-to-dot-tk-blogger.html

Only issue is that I can't get it up and running!
I have looked all over google for a tutorial on making this work, but I cannot find a solution.

Okay, basically I solved my own problem by doing this:
A Record     www.site.tk 209.85.148.121
CNAME Record www.site.tk ghs.google.com

Now my only problem is that when I look up site.tk on my address bar, nothing appears. Only www.site.tk works.

Is there a way I can forward it to www.site.tk?

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial has instructions on setting up Dot TK with Google Sites

https://sites.google.com/a/tutorialandnews.com/www/google-sites/setting-dns

Comment: When I use this method, it only seems to coverup my main ur. I want it to actually take the directories in the site. (I don't want there to be that little green icon as the logo)